# Why my figure shows up behind the text?

Tags: floats, text

I'm trying to fit one image to the page width while using a 2-column framework:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mp-f-k}
    \caption{Happy Smiley}
\end{figure}
```

However, it shows up behind the text. How can I fix that? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Use figure* (two column figure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your picture is too wide. See difference below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[height=30mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This figure is to wide}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]    
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[height=30mm,width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{This figure has correct width}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

If you need picture with width of two column, than you need to use `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}`.

**Edit:** In use of

```
\begin{figure*}[htb]
    \includegraphics[height=30mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This figure is to wide}
\end{figure*}
```

you had to be aware, that those image can appear only on top or bottom of the next page. Consequently as position options have sense only `t` and `b` or if the image take whole page, option `p`.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Yes I needed it with the width of two columns.